# Overriding equals and hashCode on a POJO with a List object

Tags: java, apache, equals, hashcode

I have a 2 POJOs that look like this

```
public class Element{
   private String name;
   private int number;
   //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}

public class Container{
    private String subject;
    private String email; 
    private List<Element> elements;
    //GETTERS AND SETTERS

}
```

And I need to verify if two Container objects are the same. I looked a bit and I found that apache commons has [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) and [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) that help overriding those methods. The idea is that those builder methods use all the elements in an Object in order to determine the HashCode and the equality of two objects. The problem is that, if you see the example code, it looks like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (obj == null) { return false; }
   if (obj == this) { return true; }
   if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
     return false;
   }
   MyClass rhs = (MyClass) obj;
   return new EqualsBuilder()
                 .appendSuper(super.equals(obj))
                 .append(field1, rhs.field1)
                 .append(field2, rhs.field2)
                 .append(field3, rhs.field3)
                 .isEquals();
  }
```

How can I append the `List<Element> elements`? Do I need to create another method just to parse the whole List into a String for this to work? Thanks!

Comment: If you can rely on the "equals" and "hashCode" implementation of "List", then according to this, ( http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) I assume you can just add it to the builder. The order of the lists must be the same to be equal as well as each element and the types stored in the list should also have equals and hashcode.

Comment: Interesting... I guess that, in order to have two Lists that have the same elements but in a different order to be considered equal, I could sort them. I'll try it out and see how it works.

Comment: or don't use a `List` at all, use a `Set` if order is not important

Comment: Be careful with this. If you are dealing with *massive* amounts of data a repeated call to the toString() (in the log.info() of example)  you may be creating a performance choke point with so deep an inspection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short version:

Yes, you can use the `append` method of `EqualsBuilder` and `HashCodeBuilder`.

Long version:

The `List.equals(Object)` method compares all the elements on the list. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.

So you could use `append(elements, rhs.elements)` to compare the lists.

The `List.hashCode()` also use the hashCode of the elements, so also can use the `append` method of `HashCodeBuilder`. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode()) says:

> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:
>
> ```
> int hashCode = 1;
> for (E e : list)
>     hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I believe both Apache Commons and auto-generated code by IDEs are based on guidelines by Joshua Block in his book [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683).

In case you use an IDE such as Eclipse you can generate equals() and hashCode() automatically by choosing which fields you would like to include in the computation. Eclipse even let's you [use your own custom equals() and hashCode() builders](https://azagorneanu.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-generate-equals-hashcode.html), or Apache Commons' for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem with you.I tried to generate equals(), hashCode() and toString() methods and the code work well.
Here is my code:

public class EmployeeIncomeTaxRespiteDto extends AbstractDto {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2305082424321176578L;

private Integer employeeId;

private String employeeName;

private List<IncomeTaxRespiteSelectDto> incomeTaxRespiteList;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, object);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EmployeeIncomeTaxRespiteDto [employeeId=" + employeeId + ", employeeName=" + employeeName + ", incomeTaxRespiteList=" + incomeTaxRespiteList + "]";
}
```

}